# I am setting up a TCP client/server program that distinguishes between two clients as X and Y in Python 3. I am having difficulty with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp

Any idea how I can have my client & server program wait until after both client connections are set up with the server, to then allow a sentence to be input into both client programs in the order they were connected? Here is what I've got so far.

```
# server.py
from socket import *
from _thread import *
import threading

serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(2) # Want to connect 2 clients
print('The server is waiting to receive 2 connections.... \n')

def ClientThread(X,Y):
        active = True
        while active:
                sentenceX = X.recv(1024).decode()
                sentenceY = Y.recv(1024).decode()
                capSentenceX = sentenceX.upper()
                catSentenceY = sentenceY.upper()

while True:
        connectionSocketX, addrX = serverSocket.accept()
        print('Accepted first connection, calling it connection X')

        connectionSocketY, addrY = serverSocket.accept()
        print('Accepted second connection, calling it connection Y\n')

        print('Waiting to receive message from client X and client Y....')

        ClientThread(connectionSocketX, connectionSocketY)
        connectionSocketX.send(capitalizedSentenceX.encode())
        connectionSocketY.send(capitalizedSentenceY.encode())
        connectionSocketX.close()
        connectionSocketY.close()
```

```
# Client.py
from socket import *

serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

sentence = input('Input lowercase sentence:')
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode())
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)

print('From Server: ', modifiedSentence.decode())

clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: It's triple backticks, not triple quotes, to mark code blocks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use threading instead of multiplexing via `select()` or `poll()`?  I think lots of new programmers choose a thread-per-client module because they think it will be easier, only to find that dealing with multiple threads is a lot trickier than multiplexing multiple sockets within a single thread.  (a multi-threaded design is particularly tricky when the threads need to communicate/coordinate/interact with each other, and that appears to be the case in your use-case)